# function over countable union, intersection, etc

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

is it true that for a give function, or a linear transformation, $L$, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, if $S=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty T_j$, then $L(S)=L(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty T_j)=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty L(T_j)$? What if each $T_j$ is compact? Is there a condition, given that the above is not true, that renders the above correct?

Comment: This is always true for any function on any domain. But it's not true if you replace the unions with intersections.